# Solaris + sort file according to date and time by sort command

Tags: linux, solaris, sort

I have along list that created in /var/tmp/file.txt from some script (in Solaris machine)
the following list have 4 fields

please advice how to sort the list according to the following TIMESTAMP ( by sort command or other solaris command )

for example the date & time 15-10-2009 08:29:18 should be before 15-10-2009 08:29:10 ... etc

example of file.txt ( not sorted file )

```
  PHONE_NUMBER         TIMESTAMP                   ID  TYPE
  -------------------- -------------------        ---- -------------- 
  972544111222         15-10-2009 08:29:18         20  sharp_gx10
  33633333333          24-09-2009 16:17:45         20  other_mm_phone
  841990000043         08-10-2009 09:04:38         60  other_mm_phone
  972541230001         08-10-2009 14:23:48         20  other_mm_phone
```

.
.
.
.

I try the sort command but not clearly why file.txt not sorted

```
sort -t' ' -k2.7,2.10n -k2.4,2.5n -k2.1,2.2n -k3 /var/tmp/file.txt
```

we get the output:

```
  5938123456789141     12-10-2009 13:09:22         20 other_phone
  5511223322332233     07-03-2012 08:13:43         20 other_phone


  888888               10-02-2012 14:13:58         60 LegacyPhone
  111111               10-02-2012 14:13:59         60 LegacyPhone
  777777               10-02-2012 14:13:59         60 LegacyPhone
  999999               16-02-2012 14:07:32         10 other_phone
  87654321             11-10-2009 09:39:37         10 other_phone
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sort -t' ' -k2.7,2.10n -k2.4,2.5n -k2.1,2.2n -k3
```

If you have control of the original script so you can print the date as YYYY-MM-DD then it would sort naturally so we would not need to pick apart the year, month and date fields in the sort command, but could just use -k2 in the same way we just use -k3 for the timestamp.

Or if I have counted your fixed width format correctly,

```
sort -k1.28,1.31n -k1.25,1.26n -k1.22,1.23n -k3
```

Or if you are not using fixed widths and have variable white space, then (`-b` to ignore spaces but note no `-n`)

```
sort -b -k2.7,2.10 -k2.4,2.5 -k2.1,2.2 -k3
```

Or to sort only part of the file (and really it would be a lot easier simply to alter the program creating this data in the first place):

```
(head -2 file; /usr/xpg4/bin/tail -n +3 file |sort -b -k2.7,2.10 -k2.4,2.5 -k2.1,2.2 -k3)
```

Comment: see my update in my question ( this isnt work well )

Comment: The problem is the -t' ' which says use ' ' as the field separator. Clearly you are not using a space. You could simply adjust the values I have given since you seem to have a fixed width format.

Comment: what you mean using? , I type exactly the sort -t' ' -k2.7,2.10n -k2.4,2.5n -k2.1,2.2n -k3 /var/tmp/file.txt
 ( in my solaris machine )

Comment: See update, since you seem to have fixed-width columns.

Comment: ok now its work - just last question if the date and time in the first field - what change need to do in your syntax ?

Comment: example - 12-10-2009 13:09:22   5938123456789141      20 other_phone

Comment: I have edited the main answer. Look at the command and read the manual: -k specifies the sort key and we need to pick out the year, month and day in that order. -k2,2 means the key starts and ends at the 2nd field and -k2.7,2.10 means start at the 7th character of the  2nd field and end at the 10th character of the 2nd field. So if the date is now the first field then change the 2 to 1. If you wrote 2010-05-27 things would be a lot easier.

Comment: one isshue the last update put the line "  PHONE_NUMBER         TIMESTAMP                   ID  TYPE" in the end , is it possible that your last update ignore from this line so this line will be in the first line as the original file ?

Comment: No but you can run two separate commands: head to give you the top of the file and tail to give you the bottom. See addition to answer.

Answer (score 0):

With complex cases like this I tend to create a temporary MySQL database and let that do the sorting or other filtering. Often it's easier to just do something like

```
CREATE TABLE temp_sort_table(phone_number VARCHAR(16), timestamp DATETIME, id INT, type VARCHAR(16))
```

or so and then just import the data from the text file to your database:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE temp_sort_table
```

Then you can easily do things like

```
SELECT * FROM temp_sort_table ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Sure, you can pass all kinds of parameters to `sort` command or apply some `awk/Perl/Python` voodoo to get all this done without a database. With complex text files it's just easier to use a database, in my opinion.

Comment: did you have example with sort command - I think its better

Comment: If you're going to load this into a database, you might as well use an SQLite one. Its a smaller footprint, and it doesn't require all of the security bits arround it.